# varnish caching external content requested by backend url

Tags: caching, reverse-proxy, varnish

I'm newbie to varnish. I want to to serve all the request from the varnish cache. My backend asked content from CDN and also from other location. Like

My varnish is example.com
backend IP 123.123.123.123
backend url request abc.jpg with a link
http://web.example.com/api/abc.jpg
and
some CDN content like
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js

Normally they are not being cached. Served directly to the client browser from their origin location.
How to use varnish cache all of them and set a cache lifetime ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Varnish Cache uses static backends. You can  define the backends explicitly for each external resource you need (web.example.com, cdnjs.cloudflare.com, ...). This has to happen ahead of time and cannot be done on-the-fly.

However, [Varnish Enterprise](https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/varnish-enterprise/), the commercial version of Varnish offers a module that supports dynamic backends. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/ for more info.

Comment: I've already defined 2 backend to achieve this. Like backend web {
    .host = "web.example.com";
    .port = "80";
    .max_connections = 100;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6s;
    .connect_timeout = 20s;
}  and at vcl_rcv{ if (req.url ~ "^/api/") {
        set req.backend_hint = web;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    } but no request are going through the varnish for web.example.com

Comment: @MuhammadSaifulAmin `web.example.com` doesn't really exist as a hostname, it doesn't resolve to an IP address. It is probably used as a boilerplate URL in some example code. It should be replaced with an actual hostname that exists.

Comment: I've set an actual domain instead of web.example.com, here I'm just using it as example.

Comment: @MuhammadSaifulAmin In that case, please run a `varnishlog -g request` for the failing request. If you have difficulties interpreting the output, please add the logging output to your original question and I'll help you out. The will probably tell why it can't connect.